# Using GridSearchCV object gives an AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

The ultimate goal here is to find the feature names used in the best fit. I assume that the `feature_names_in_` attribute is just what I want. However, running the below code I get the error outlined in the title of this post.

```
x = aligned_data[['rawPress1Scaled', 'rawTemp1Scaled']].to_numpy()

# calculate all the terms (4th order) for the x data
poly = PolynomialFeatures(4, include_bias=False)
x_train = poly.fit_transform(x)
x_train = pd.DataFrame(x_train, columns=poly.get_feature_names())
y_train = aligned_data[const.CAL1_PRESS_LABEL]

# define model
model = ElasticNet()
# define the cross-validation model
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
# define the grid search and search model
grid = dict()
length, start, stop = (20, -6, 0)
alphas = np.logspace(start=start, stop=stop, num=length, endpoint=True, base=10)
grid['alpha'] = alphas.tolist()
grid['l1_ratio'] = [1]
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=grid, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', refit='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)

# perform the search
results = search.fit(x_train, y_train)

# summarize
print("MAE: {}".format(results.best_score_))
print("Config: {}".format(results.best_params_))
print("Feature names: {}".format(results.feature_names_in_))
```

I have dug around in the documentation for how to get feature_names_in_ to work and this page [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit) seems to indicate that:

> feature_names_in_ndarray of shape (n_features_in_,)
> Names of features seen during fit. Only defined if best_estimator_ is defined (see the documentation for the refit parameter for more details) and that best_estimator_ exposes feature_names_in_ when fit.

So I have checked that the `refit` parameter is definitely set to `true` and that the `best_estimator` is defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The docs say that its define if both conditions are true: "`best_estimator_` is defined" (which does in your case) AND "`best_estimator_` exposes `feature_names_in_` when fit". Are you sure that your `ElasticNet` instance has that attribute?

Comment: @aaossa the `best_estimator` is of type `Elasticnet`. At this stage it doesn't look like the `best_estimator` has the `feature_names_in_` exposed. On further inspection, I actually think the `feature_names_in` isn't what I want anyway. I want to know what features were used in the `elasticnet` not all the features that went in. does that make sense?

Comment: You mean something like importance? Maybe the `coef_` attribute?

Comment: @aaossa the `coef_` attribute does give me the values of the coefficients. But how do I know what the feature names are? In my case, I have have two independent variables. I pass to the ElasticNet a 4th order PolynomialFeatures which means I end up with 14 terms plus a coefficient. This is what is **seen during the fit** but in some cases, the elasticnet may find a best fit that doesn't need all those features, and some are dropped. So I need to not only know the coefficient values, but also the feature names for these coefficient values. does that make sense? thanks for your help so far

Comment: @aaossa for further clarification: elastic net is an 'embedded method' for feature selection. It basically uses a combination of L1 and L2 penalty to shrink the coefficients of those 'unimportant' features to 0 or near zero

Comment: If I'm understanding the docs correctly, both `feature_names_in_` and `coef_` are in the same order. You could confirm this by training a model and then switching your columns to train a new model. You should see how `feature_names_in_` and `coef_` reach the same values as befre but in a different order

Comment: Thanks for the insight but I really want to know the `feature_names_out`. To clarify: I want to know the features used in the best fit **after** any low-scoring features are removed. Does that make sense?